# My swiper with Swiper.js stop autoplay after slide it with finger, why?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.myswiper', {
        autoplay: 3000,
        simulateTouch: true,
        loop: true,
        preloadImages: true,
        speed: 200,
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination'
    });
```

While this is my initial swiper, and when I drag it with mouse or touch it with finger and then slided it, my swiper stops auto playback, how to fix it?

Comment: can you share your html or Fiddle.

Answer (score 28):

It's now 'disableOnInteraction'

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    scrollbar: { el: '.swiper-scrollbar' },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to find the answer in [API of Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.V81pkpN97MU), like [Autoplay Demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/21-autoplay.html).

You should insert the swipe attribute below:

```
autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
```

The instruction of this attribute:

> Set to false and autoplay will not be disabled after user interactions
>   (swipes), it will be restarted every time after interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use autoplay as define here

```
  autoplay={{
               delay: 2500,
               disableOnInteraction: false,
            }}
```